# What to do with overlay when the user browser is zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an overlay on my site which is activated by users when they click on a button.

This overlay looks and works just fine. That is until the user decides to zoom there browser. When the browser is zoomed because the overlay utilises position:fixed it does not scroll nor can the user get to or see the submit button.

This for some visually impaired users is not desirable. Does anyone know how I could do detect something on the fly and perhaps detect and redirect to a form contained on a static page instead.

Comment: Can you post some code to replicate this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zooming has a similar effect to resizing the window so I think (correct me if I'm wrong) but you can use a `resize()` event to update the overlays width and height. Please see below for an example.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   $('#Overlay').css({
      height:window.innerHeight,
      width:window.innerWidth
   )};
});
```

**EDIT**

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xR5Sc/1/) which works with the zooming of the browser as well as resizing the window.

Comment: I think this is precisely what i'm looking for. I need to test it so as soon as I get a chance to do that I will accept the answer. Tks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the problem here, you have an overlay, but the overlay... is overlaying something, and that seems to be a problem?

Well anyway, I usually do overlays like this:

```
.overlay {
    background-color: #777;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    /* This is important, maybe what you're after, the content you want 
       to show has to have a higher z-index than the overlay itself! */
    z-index: 99; 
}
```

The z-index will allow you to chose the stacking order of elements, perhaps that will solve your problem.